# Updating multiple (100+) table column value having same data structure

Tags: oracle

I am new for Oracle. I have some query if you can solve I am very thankful to you.

Details Given below,

```
Database name:Paul

Schema: ddpaul

table: table_12_101, table_12_102, table_12_199,..........
```

These tables have same data structure.

Column names:

```
ID, Number, Comp, Module, etc..
```

Now, I have to update/alter Column "COMP" IN ALL TABLE USING SQL/PROCEDURE.

Any method to select "COMP" from all tables at once in one column?

After saving to excel I will change required values.

Main thing is now,

I want to update "COMP" as per new excel data with respect to old one.

```
Table_12_101,......

ID | COMP | MODULE

56623114 | FA-5920-01 | FA1 

56623110 | FA-5921-01 | FA1
```

e.g. COMP changed to CA-5920-01 or need to remove FA- etc.

Please any one help for above. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: If you have 100 tables all with the same structure you almost certainly should redesign your database schema.

Comment: To select COMP from all table , you can use `select t1.COMP || ',' || t2.COMP || ',' || t3.COMP from table_12_101 t1 , table_12_102 t2 , table_12_199 t3`  **Separated by (,) **. Which DB are you using ? as `mysql` n `oracle` are two diiferent db's , have there different query structure. **second question unclear.**

Comment: Your tables are certainly not normalized.

Comment: This database is created by Software. I can not change it.

Comment: As this database structure is used from last 20 years by company

Comment: I don't want to type every table names in query. Any other way? Please

Comment: This is tagged both "oracle" and "mysql".  It should only have one of these tags.

Comment: @BhartenduPatni : In responce to " Any method to select "COMP" from all tables at once in one column?" You can write anonymous block to generate query but you have to execute it explicitly.

Comment: You try other-wise i will give you

Comment: I don't know Oracle, so if possible then i request you to please give me code for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can find table name with such column by query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM USER_TAB_COLS where column_name = 'COMP';
```

And use this name in procedure to execute updates.

Answer (score 0):

In Response to : Any method to select "COMP" from all tables at once in one column ?

The below block will give you dynamic query that you have to run individually.

AS Its giving you dynamic query , you dont have to write all table name in query , it will generate it automatially.

```
    declare
    after_from varchar2(10000) :=NULL;
    before_from varchar2(10000) :=NULL;
    final_query varchar2(20000) :=NULL;
    temp1 integer ;
    begin
    temp1 :=0;
    for x in ( SELECT table_name FROM USER_TAB_COLS where column_name = 'COMP') loop
    temp1 := temp1+1;
    before_from := before_from || ' t'||temp1||'.COMP||'',''||';
    after_from := after_from || x.table_name || ' t' ||temp1||' , ';
    end loop;
    before_from:=substr(before_from,1,length(before_from)-7);
    after_from:=substr(after_from,1,length(after_from)-3);
    final_query := 'SELECT '||before_from||' FROM '||after_from||';';
    dbms_output.put_line(final_query);
    end;
    /
```